# Lagging/Stutter performance box shadow based on mouse position

Tags: javascript, css

I've coded a box shadow drop for images in my element where it'll respond to the position of the mouse. It works well if the box shadow effect were to run on only one element. However, when running on multiple elements it starts to lag/stutter. I am unclear as to what is causing it. I'm hoping someone can clarify it.

Here is a short video of what I'm experiencing:-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ULahZWR5sKt-yaDEIjEvK3TFa1g1n65d/view

Attached is my code;

HTML:

```
<div class="header-image">
   <img class="images shadow-effect" src="./images/baby-swimming-classes.jpg" alt="Baby Swimming Class">
   <img class="images shadow-effect" src="./images/children-swimming-classes.jpg" alt="Children Swimming Class">
   <img class="images shadow-effect" src="./images/pre-competitive-swimming-classes.jpg" alt="Pre-Competitive Swimming Class">
   <img class="images shadow-effect" src="./images/adult-swimming-classes.jpg" alt="Adult Swimming Class">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

const eleShadow = Object.values($('.shadow-effect'));
const shadowMax = 20; //px

// 1. Getting the required information
function boxShadow(e) {

    //Screen width and height
    const {
        width: screenWidth,
        height: screenHeight
    } = screen;

    //Mouse position
    const {
        clientX: mouseX,
        clientY: mouseY
    } = e;

    //Position of objects
    const {
        x: eleX,
        y: eleY,
        width: eleWidth,
        height: eleHeight
    } = eleShadow[0].getBoundingClientRect();

    const shadowX = (((eleX + (eleWidth / 2)) - mouseX) / screenWidth) * shadowMax;
    const shadowY = (((eleY + (eleHeight / 2)) - mouseY) / screenHeight) * shadowMax;

    // eleShadow[0].style.boxShadow = `${shadowX}px ${shadowY}px 0 #EF5B5B`;

    $(".shadow-effect").css("box-shadow",
        `${shadowX}px ${shadowY}px 0 #EF5B5B`
    );

    // For each individual element

}

$(document).on('mousemove', boxShadow);
})
```

Update:-
It's smooth up to 3 images, when the 4th image comes in. It begins to lag. However, sometimes 4 images is smooth but when I refresh it may stutter again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many events triggering as it is a `mousemove` event on `document`. Try throttling down the triggers a bit.

```js
/* eslint-disable no-undef*/

$(document).ready(function () {
  const eleShadow = Object.values($(".shadow-effect"));
  const shadowMax = 20; //px

  // Throttle function: Input as function which needs to be throttled and delay is the time interval in milliseconds
  let timerId;
  const throttleFunction = (func, delay) => {
    // If setTimeout is already scheduled, no need to do anything
    if (timerId) {
      return;
    }

    // Schedule a setTimeout after delay seconds
    timerId = setTimeout(function () {
      func();

      // Once setTimeout function execution is finished, timerId = undefined so that in <br>
      // the next scroll event function execution can be scheduled by the setTimeout
      timerId = undefined;
    }, delay);
  };

  // 1. Getting the required information
  function boxShadow(e) {
    //Screen width and height
    const { width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight } = window.screen;

    //Mouse position
    const { clientX: mouseX, clientY: mouseY } = e;

    //Position of objects
    const {
      x: eleX,
      y: eleY,
      width: eleWidth,
      height: eleHeight
    } = eleShadow[0].getBoundingClientRect();

    const shadowX = ((eleX + eleWidth / 2 - mouseX) / screenWidth) * shadowMax;
    const shadowY =
      ((eleY + eleHeight / 2 - mouseY) / screenHeight) * shadowMax;

    // eleShadow[0].style.boxShadow = `${shadowX}px ${shadowY}px 0 #EF5B5B`;

    $(".shadow-effect").css(
      "box-shadow",
      `${shadowX}px ${shadowY}px 0 #EF5B5B`
    );

    // For each individual element
  }

  $(document).on("mousemove", (e) => throttleFunction(() => boxShadow(e), 50));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header-image">
      <img
        class="images shadow-effect"
        src="https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg"
        alt="Baby Swimming Class"
        width="200"
      />
      <img
        class="images shadow-effect"
        src="https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg"
        alt="Children Swimming Class"
        width="200"
      />
      <img
        class="images shadow-effect"
        src="https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg"
        alt="Pre-Competitive Swimming Class"
        width="200"
      />
      <img
        class="images shadow-effect"
        src="https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg"
        alt="Adult Swimming Class"
        width="200"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can play around with the delay and find an optimum value for performance and experience

Comment: Thanks @Akhil, i'll try this out. However, I understand that it could be too many events being triggered, but why is it ok when I have the effect on 3 images, 1 input element, and button element but it doesn't work well on 4 images.

Comment: Huh, It doesn't work. even with 25ms timeout.. it still lags/stutter. Could it be a computer performance issue?

Comment: I've stopped using the shadow-effect function and just use box-shadow styling on css that shifts in direction when clicked ... it also lags. Not sure if, the function is the problem anymore hmm .

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the stutter/lagging issue is not with JavaScript but with file size. Due to one of the image's file size being too big. Compressing the images would help.  Furthermore, keeping the images as original with the property and value below also causes stutter.

```
object-fit: cover;
```

Using any other value other than cover seems to solve the issue while maintaining the images but its not what I want in an image container.